# How can i know where is jquery ui.autocomplete plugin attached to the element

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools, addeventlistener

I use Chrome built-in Dev Tools.

All I see are big arrays 
[image]
and I can't realize at least 
**what file contains  a "change"/"keypress" event**
or better **what plugin is used**.

P.S. I found the ui-autocomplete call in my js-files.
The question is about using Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: I didn't understand your question - *"How can i know where is jquery ui.autocomplete"*.. what do you mean where..? on which element it is initialized..?

Comment: This plugin too nice http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event

Comment: @T J I mean how can i know in what file ui-autocomplete was initialized. Sorry for my English.